# Play (looped) audio file on Apple Watch with WatchOS 2.0

Tags: avfoundation, avaudioplayer, watchkit, watchos-2

What's the best way to play a (looped) audio file on the Apple Watch?

The file would be the same always. If I could have an audio player (AVAudioPlayer?) and set it to loop indefinitely (like it's possible on iOS), that would be ideal.

I tried searching Apple's documentation (being logged in as an Apple Developer) but I couldn't find anything.

Looking forward to your enlightening replies!

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using this method to play a media file: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion: